# How to use multithreading with tkinter to update a label and simultaneously perform calculations in a thread controlled by button events?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter, queue

I'm trying to start a counter that displays the value in a label on a separate display window.
The main window has a START, STOP and DISPLAY button.
The START must start the counter, STOP must stop it and the display window must open only when I click on DISPLAY button.

Here's what I have so far. The buttons seem to be unresponsive and the display window pops up without user intervention. How can I fix this?

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading
import queue


def Run_Device(disp_q,flaq_q):
    temp_q = queue.Queue()
    temp_q.put(0)
    while(flaq_q.empty()):
        #time.sleep(0.2)
        count = temp_q.get()
        count += 1
        temp_q.put(count)
        disp_q.put(count)
    else:
        flaq_q.queue.clear()


def P_Window(disp_q):
    pw = tk.Tk()
    value_label = tk.Label(pw, text=disp_q.get(), relief='sunken', bg='lemon chiffon', font='Helvetica 16 bold')
    value_label.pack()
    def update_values():
        value_label.config(text=disp_q.get())  
        value_label.after(1000,update_values)   
    update_values()

    pw.mainloop()

def Stop_Dev(flaq_q):
    flaq_q.put("Stop")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    disp_q = queue.Queue()
    flaq_q = queue.Queue()

    t_device = threading.Thread(target=Run_Device, args=(disp_q, flaq_q), name="Device 1")
    t_disp = threading.Thread(target=P_Window, args=(disp_q, ), name="Display 1")

    window = tk.Tk()

    start_button = tk.Button(window, text='Start', command=t_device.start(), bg='spring green', font='Helvetica 12 bold', width=20, state='normal', relief='raised')
    start_button.pack()

    stop_button = tk.Button(window, text='Stop', command=lambda: Stop_Dev(flaq_q), bg='OrangeRed2', font='Helvetica 12 bold', width=20, state='normal', relief='raised')
    stop_button.pack()

    disp_param_button = tk.Button(window, text='Display', command=t_disp.start(), bg='sky blue', font='Helvetica 12 bold', width=20, state='normal', relief='raised')
    disp_param_button.pack()

    window.mainloop()
```

I'm trying to learn how to use multithreading in tkinter so any feedback would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues I see with your code.  The first is just simple bugs, e.g.:

```
start_button = tk.Button(window, text='Start', command=t_device.start(), ...
```

here it should be `command=t_device.start` otherwise the command is the function returned by `t_device.start()`

The second is you've not dealt with various "What if ...?" scenarios, e.g. What if the user pushes 'Start' or 'Display' multiple times?

I've tried to address the above in my rework below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep
from queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import Thread

FONT = 'Helvetica 16 bold'

def run_device():
    count = 0

    while flaq_q.empty():
        count += 1
        disp_q.put(count)
        sleep(0.5)

    while not flaq_q.empty():  # flaq_q.queue.clear() not documented
        flaq_q.get(False)

def p_window():
    global pw

    if pw is None:

        pw = tk.Toplevel()

        value_label = tk.Label(pw, text=disp_q.get(), width=10, font=FONT)
        value_label.pack()

        def update_values():
            if not disp_q.empty():
                try:
                    value_label.config(text=disp_q.get(False))
                except Empty:
                    pass
            pw.after(250, update_values)

        update_values()

    elif pw.state() == 'normal':
        pw.withdraw()
    else:
        pw.deiconify()

def stop_device():
    if flaq_q.empty():
        flaq_q.put("Stop")

def start_device():
    global device

    if device and device.is_alive():
        return

    while not disp_q.empty():
        disp_q.get(False)

    disp_q.put(0)

    device = Thread(target=run_device)
    device.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    disp_q = Queue()
    flaq_q = Queue()

    root = tk.Tk()

    pw = None
    device = None

    tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start_device, width=20, font=FONT).pack()
    tk.Button(root, text='Stop', command=stop_device, width=20, font=FONT).pack()
    tk.Button(root, text='Display', command=p_window, width=20, font=FONT).pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

I've left out some details to simplify the example.  Even with its additional checks, it's still nowhere near perfect.  (E.g. it hangs if you don't 'Stop' before you close the window, etc.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. You have taught me a few new methods in tkinter that I was unaware of. I have another question. Are Queues initialized in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` method available for use throughout the program without having  to use global inside those sections? I was under the assumption that the queues had to be passed to every function in the program

Comment: @Shawn, variables in Python are either global or belong to a function, there are no block-scope variables.  So the variables defined under a `if __name__ == "__main__"` are global.  Variables defined inside a `def main():` are not.

Comment: @Shawn, but be aware:  the reason to have a `if __name__ == "__main__"` is if you believe your file can also be used a module in an `import`, then imported functions you use will require that things like `disp_q` be defined globally.  So, in this case, making them arguments makes sense.  For purposes of a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I generally don't include "__main__" logic as its usually not applicable to the specific issue at hand.

Comment: So I modified the code a little by adding a second thread such that it writes to the values to a csv row after row. I changed the device `sleep` to 0.3s, the label `after` is still 250ms and the `sleep` on the csv thread is 2s. But the csv thread works perfect only at certain times. I'm guessing it's a timing issue. How did you calculate the sleep times for the thread?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to adapt something like the following:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import queue
import time


def run_device():
    for i in range(4):
        print(i)
    pass


def process_queue(MyQueue):
    """Check if we got a complete message from our thread.
    Start the next operation if we are ready"""

    try:
        # when our thread completes its target function (task),
        # the supplied message is added to the queue
        msg = MyQueue.get(0)
        # check message
        print(msg)
    except queue.Empty:
        # .get failed, come back in 100 and check again
        print('no message')
        threading.Timer(0.001, lambda q=MyQueue: process_queue(q)).start()


class ThreadedTask(threading.Thread):
    """threaded task handler"""
    def __init__(self, queue, target, msg):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        # message to add to queue when the task (target function) completes
        self.msg = msg
        # function to run
        self._target = target
        # queue to store completion message
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        """called when object is instantiated"""
        # start users task
        try:
            self._target()
        except Exception as e:
            self.queue.put('Thread Fail')
            return
        # we are done, pass the completion message
        self.queue.put(self.msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyQueue = queue.Queue()
    MyThread = ThreadedTask(MyQueue, run_device, 'Thread Task: Run')
    MyThread.start()
    process_queue(MyQueue)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I saw a similar example like this online. But I had a hard time replicating it such that the results are displayed on a separate window and are constantly getting updated in the background even when the window was closed. I think it is because of my lack of understanding of how Queues work.

Comment: No problem, seems you got sorted. Figured I would edit the post anyway, its now a working example.